# Buildfire: Search field in people plugin

Tags: json, plugins, directory

Buildfire: I need to use the people plugin but it does not have a search function. I have all the coding with my color scheme to add the search function to the plugin. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fork the existing [People Plugin](https://github.com/BuildFire/peoplePlugin), and add your search logic to it and customize it as you like. If you'd like to learn more about how to code plugins, [here's](https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-create-a-Plugin) a good place to get started.